# searching technic on multiple parameters which may be null

Tags: java, search

I am trying to implement searching technic which will take four parameters and returns a set of matched results.
method signature looks like

```
public Set<Mobile> search(Set<Mobile> mobiles, OperatingSystem os,
        Brand brand,Display display, Style style);
```

parameters may be null if they don't want to search for that particular property.ex: the operating system may be null but a user may provide brand, display, and style.

I have tried with all 16 possible combinations like by checking null on each property which I feel not a good option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's the right approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you could do something like this instead:

```
public Set<Mobile> search(Set<Mobile> mobiles, OperatingSystem os,
        Brand brand,Display display, Style style) {
    Set<Mobile> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (Set<Mobile> mobile: mobiles) {
        if ((os == null || os.equals(mobile.getOs()))
                && (brand == null || brand.equals(mobile.getBrand()))
                && (display == null || display.equals(mobile.getDisplay()))
                && (style == null || style.equals(mobile.getStyle()))) {
            result.add(mobile);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```